# Existence of a unique solution to Cauchy problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis, cauchy-problem

Let $X$ Hilbert space.
Let $\mathcal{A}:D(\mathcal A)\subset X\rightarrow X$ nonlinear and $f:[0,+\infty)\rightarrow X$
$$\begin{cases}U_{t}(t)=\mathcal{A} U(t)+f(t),& \forall t>0, \\ U(0)=U_{0}\end{cases} $$
I search for references of  theorems which allow to me to have the existence and uniqueness of a solution $U$ in $[0,+\infty)$.

I have found some theorems but in the case where $U$ is defined on $[0,T]$ not on $[0,+\infty)$ and for the inclusion cauchy problem .I mean in this case:

$\mathcal{A}:D(\mathcal A)\subset X\rightarrow X$ nonlinear and $f:[0,T]\rightarrow X$
$$\begin{cases}U_{t}(t)\in\mathcal{A} U(t)+f(t),& \forall t\in[0,T], \\U(0)=U_{0}\end{cases} $$
Remark:

If $X$ Hilbert space et  $A:D(A)\subset X \rightarrow X$ nonlinear operator.
Cauchy problem is given by :
\begin{eqnarray}
f(t)&\in&U_t(t)+AU(t) \;t \in [0,T]\\
U(0)&=&U_0
\end{eqnarray}
$A$ is$\omega$-m accretive if:

$\langle (A+\omega I) U,U\rangle \geq 0 $ et $R(I+\lambda A)=X $ for some  $\lambda >0$, $\omega \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Theorem:If $A$ is $\omega$-m accretive, $u_0 \in \overline{D(A)}$ and$ f \in L^1(0,T;X)$ then the above Cauchy problem has a unique une solution  $ u\in C([0,T];\overline{D(A)})$ (Book "Nonlinear differential equations of monotone types in Banach spaces")

I'd know if there is a reference where I can found this result in $\mathbb{R_+}$ and with equality not inclusion I mean
\begin{eqnarray}
U_t(t)+AU(t)&=&f(t) \;t \in [0, \mathbb{R}_+)\\
U(0)&=&U_0
\end{eqnarray}
if A est $\omega$-m accretive , $u_0 \in \overline{D(A)}$ and $ f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}_+;X)$  then the above Cauchy problem  has a unique solution   $u\in C(\mathbb{R}_+;\overline{D(A)})$ ???

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for local existence (ie $U(t)$ and $f(t)$ still defined on $[0,+\infty)$, and there exists $T$ possibly but not necessarily $= + \infty$ such that a unique solution $U(t)$ exists on $[0,T)$?); or global existence (ie existence and uniqueness on entire $[0,+\infty)$)?

For general local existence results, see
"Remarks on blow-up and nonexistence theorems for nonlinear evolution equations" (1977) by J.M Ball (https://academic.oup.com/qjmath/article/28/4/473/1563956).

To extend general local existence results to global existence, you will have to prove a continuation theorem (ie norms of the form: $\|\cdot \|_{[0,T],X} < + \infty$ implies solution can be extended locally for $t \geq T$) and show that the such a norm does not blow up in finite time assuming a smooth solution. An example of such a continuation theorem can be found in "Remarks on the breakdown of smooth solutions for the 3-D Euler equations" (1984) by Beale, Kato, and Majda (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/bf01212349) for the 3D Euler Equation.

Comment: I have added a remark to explain what I want exactly in the first post.

Comment: I don't think I can help with that though - sorry about that, but I hope you can find someone that can help you with it